# What is exact definition of 'wronskian' for ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

The problem said "Determine the longest interval in which the given initial value problem is certain to have the solution.

given problem is 
$$x(x-15)y''+16xy'+4y=2, \quad y(14)=0, y'(14)= -1$$

so I change the equation to 
$$y''+\frac{16}{x-15}y'+\frac{4}{x(x-15)}y=\frac{2}{x(x-15)}$$

In this case the problem means that determine the **wronskian** of ODE?
and if my thought is right, this equation is when $x\neq0,15$ the $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ is continuous. so the answer of problem is $ 0\lt x \lt 15$

Is my answer and thought is right?

Comment: I am a little confused - the question you write in the body of your question is very different to the one in the title. You don't use anything related to any wronskian to come up with your answer either

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the Wronskian $W[y_1,y_2]=y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2$.

What you need is the statement that on each interval $[a,b]$ where the coefficients in the second form/changed equation are continuous, the ODE is Lipschitz using the maxima of these continuous functions on a closed interval. Thus a solution exists and can be extended to any larger interval satisfying the same condition. In the union of all these intervals you can indeed cover the open interval $(0,15)$, which then is the domain of all maximal solutions to initial values inside this interval.